# hive - replace value of next record based on current value

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have dataset as shown in below image[image]

When **is_session_change** value is true i am populating new value for **session** column and i want to carry that session value till the next TRUE value of **is_session_change** column.
For example below image - [image]

Column expected_session is the expected value. Please let me know if anyone can help!! Thanks in advance.
Actually i am processing the data hourly, and for particular run i am processing current hour data plus last hour data, so last hour data will have session ids attached properly, now i am trying to extend those session ids for eligible records in current hour, if record is not eligible to extend i am generating new session id.

I have tried below approach which have populated values in session column -

```
select *,case when (session_id != '-1')  then session_id 
              when (new_session = true) then  getSessionId() 
              when (new_session =false AND session_id = '-1') then LAG(session_id) OVER (PARTITION BY uniquevisitor ORDER BY ts) 
        else '-' END as abc 
from mktg_web.web_session_final 
order by uniquevisitor
```

Comment: have you tried solving it at all? if so, show us your attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vamsi, i have updated the question with my attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the occurrence column to group the values based on session. Use a `case` expression to set `-1` values to `null` and use `max` window function to get the expected_session value.

```
select w.*,max(case when session <> -1 then session end) 
           over(partition by uniquevisitor,occurrence) as expected_session 
from mktg_web.web_session_final w
```